# how would I insert chests and robbers into this grid?

Tags: python-2.7

```
arena=[]
def grid(place):
    for i in range(8):
        place.append(["O"]*8)
def string(alist):
    for i in alist:
        print(" ".join(i))
grid(arena)
previous_postion_y= 2
previous_postion_x= 2
postion_y= 0
postion_x= 7
arena[postion_x][postion_y] = "x"
string(arena)
game = True
while True:
    try:
        while game:
            print("")
            print("")
            print("")
            print("You are displayed on the grid as: X")
            print("")
            print("You can now move Left, Right, Up, Down or stop")
            print("")
            print("")
            move= input("What move would you like to make: ")
            move = move.lower()
            if move == "stop" or move== "s":
                clearpage()
                print("you will be transported to the main menu")
                print("")
                print("")
                print("Press enter to continue...")
                start()
            elif move == "up" or move =="u":
                spaces = int(input("How many spaces would you like to move."))
                arena[postion_x][postion_y] = "O"
                postion_x = postion_x - spaces
            elif move == "down" or move == "d":
                spaces = int(input("How many spaces would you like to move."))
                arena[postion_x][postion_y] = "O"
                postion_x = postion_x + spaces
            elif move == "left" or move == "l":
                spaces = int(input("How many spaces would you like to move."))
                arena[postion_x][postion_y] = "O"
                postion_y = postion_y - spaces
            elif move == "right" or move =="r":
                spaces = int(input("How many spaces would you like to move."))
                arena[postion_x][postion_y] = "O"
                postion_y = postion_y + spaces
            else:
                print("")
                print("")
                print("")
                print("Please enter one of the following commands.")
                print("Left.")
                print("Right.")
                print("Up.")
                print("Down")
                print("Stop")
                print("")
                input("Please press enter to continue...")
                arena[postion_x][postion_y] = "X"
            arena[postion_x][postion_y] = "X"
            string(arena)
            print("")
        except IndexError:
            print("")
            print("")
            print("You cant leave the premises of the grid")
            print("")
            print("Please enter a valid direction")
            print("")
            print("")
            input("Press enter to continue...")
        arena[postion_x][postion_y] = "X"
        string(arena)
```

I need to insert chests and bandits in this game but don't know how to
the aim of the game is that each chest will add ten points and a bandit will cause a loss of all points.
there are 10 chests and 5 bandits

Answer (score 0):

As a very general approach to your question, you might find the code posted below useful as a starting point. It will generate a random 5x5 'arena' (grid) where each cell may potentially contain a robber or chest.

```
from random import Random


class GridItem(object):
    pass


class Robber(GridItem):
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'R'


class Chest(GridItem):
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'C'


class EmptySpace(GridItem):
    def __repr__(self):
        return ' '


def create_arena(width, height, robber_gen_chance, chest_gen_chance):
    random = Random()
    arena = []

    for x in range(width):
        column = []
        for y in range(height):
            if random.random() <= robber_gen_chance:
                column.append(Robber())
            elif random.random() <= chest_gen_chance:
                column.append(Chest())
            else:
                column.append(EmptySpace())

        arena.append(column)

    return arena


def print_arena(arena):
    for row in arena:
        print(row)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    arena = create_arena(5, 5, 0.1, 0.1)
    print_arena(arena)
```

**Output**

```
[ ,  ,  ,  , C]
[R,  ,  ,  ,  ]
[ ,  ,  , C,  ]
[ ,  ,  ,  ,  ]
[ ,  ,  ,  ,  ]
```

---

I just saw your stipulation:

> there are 10 chests and 5 bandits

Here's an alternative implementation that will guarantee a specified number of robbers and chests will be present in each arena. Their positions will be randomly generated, and an exception will be raised if the arena is too small to fit them:

```
from random import Random


class GridItem(object):
    pass


class Robber(GridItem):
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'R'


class Chest(GridItem):
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'C'


class EmptySpace(GridItem):
    def __repr__(self):
        return ' '


def create_arena(width, height, num_robbers, num_chests):
    total_cells = width * height
    if total_cells < num_robbers + num_chests:
        raise ValueError('Not enough spaces for robbers and chests')

    random = Random()
    arena = [[EmptySpace() for _ in range(height)] for _ in range(width)]

    available_spaces = set(range(total_cells))
    robbers_at = set(random.sample(available_spaces, num_robbers))
    available_spaces.difference_update(robbers_at)
    chests_at = set(random.sample(available_spaces, num_chests))

    # A robber and chest should never share the same position
    assert robbers_at.isdisjoint(chests_at)

    for position in robbers_at:
        i, j = position // width, position % width
        arena[i][j] = Robber()

    for position in chests_at:
        i, j = position // width, position % width
        arena[i][j] = Chest()

    return arena


def print_arena(arena):
    for row in arena:
        print(row)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    arena = create_arena(10, 10, 5, 10)
    print_arena(arena)
```

**Output**

```
[ ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , R,  , R, C]
[ ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , C,  , C]
[ ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ]
[ ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , C, R,  ,  ]
[ ,  ,  ,  , C,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ]
[C,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , C,  ,  ]
[ ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , C,  ,  ]
[ ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , R,  ,  ]
[ ,  ,  , R,  ,  ,  ,  , C,  ]
[ ,  , C,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ]
```